# write behind cache Ehcache new feature?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, ehcache

i looking for guide/document/tutorial on how to use this new feature write-behind-cache in ehcache? Is there any demo in spring+jpa+ehcache+hibernate?

just to clariyfing, write-behind-cache mean each time we persist entity, it will be written into cache rather than into database correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that Ehcache offers Write-Behind Caching does **NOT** mean that any piece of software using Ehcache, like Hibernate, can leverage it without modification. From [Terracotta's Hibernate Integration](http://tusharkhairnar.blogspot.com/2009/06/terracottas-hibernate-integration.html) (note that this is a non independent post i.e. pro caching):

> #### Write-Behind Caching
>
> When you think of cache you will arrive at
>   these cache strategies : Read-Through
>   Caching, Write-Through Caching,
>   Write-Behind Caching. **Hibernate Second
>   Level cache is Read-Write-Through
>   Cache** where if cache miss occurs,
>   entity is read from database and then
>   handed over to cache for susequent
>   access. **But H2LC is not Write-Behind
>   caching**. With Terracotta's disk
>   persistence and asynchronsous module
>   it would be really efficient for
>   certain use-cases to implement
>   write-behind. **Currently Hibernate just
>   directly writes to database**. Instead
>   if its modified to write to second
>   level cache and persistent
>   async-database-queue, this would
>   decrease latency and increase
>   throughput dramatically.

In other words, write-behind caching is just not how Hibernate currently works (and I may be wrong but I don't think this is going to change in a a near future). But feel free to raise a [Jira](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH) issue :)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/05/ehcache-2.0

> Ehcache 2.0 introduces write-through
>   and write-behind caching.
>   Write-through caching pattern is used
>   by the applications to write data to
>   the cache which causes writes to an
>   underlying resource (e.g. a database).
>   The cache acts as a facade to the
>   underlying resource. **Write-behind
>   caching pattern uses the same client
>   API, but the write happens
>   asynchronously.** The write-behind
>   caching feature, supported as part of
>   the new Ehcache API, works with
>   asynchronous batching of updates to
>   the database.

Comment: ya man, that is the article that I read before posted the question. no tutorial how to use with spring+jpa+hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you, just thought I'd mention [GigaSpaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com/).

Comment: Hibernate second level cache is not write-behind caching, regardless of the L2 caching provider you use (coherence, ehcache, gigaspace, whatever).

Comment: I mention GigaSpaces to a user asking about write-behind caching and y ou downvote? Why? Whyyyyyyyyyy!